# How to force width when the screen width gets smaller in css?

Tags: css, media-queries, width

(demo page)
https://mightyvoicer.herokuapp.com/

I wanna to ask that why would the display box be broken when I get my screen smaller.

I will appreciate your help very much.

[Full-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTJiL.jpg)

[Small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My68O.jpg)

Comment: Please note [so] is not so much about other people helping you, but about you helping other people. In order to do that, you must make sure any answer to your question and the question itself will remain relevant to future visitors, even after you fix the problem in your project. Therefore, you must add a [mcve] of your problem ***in the question itself***. Use the `<>` button to add a live snippet to your question and link all required resources making sure the problem is replicated in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this CSS to keep it from being distorted:

```
.pie-chart {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

To keep them centered on really narrow devices, you probably want to add this to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  #root>.container { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```